# Как во время исполнения Python кода скрыть командную строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос такой 
Как во время исполнения Python кода скрыть командную строку 
В смысле она в начале должна открыться 
После ввода данных пользователя закрыться

PS Это не вредоносная программа. Это программа для выключения ПК по таймеру

Comment: Прочитайте про библиотеку python-daemo, должно помочь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-хорошему нужно сделать нормальный оконный интерфейс. Но если очень нужно, то есть функции WinAPI (предполагаю, что у вас Windows):

- [`FreeConsole`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) - освободить консоль
- [`AllocConsole`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) - создать консоль

Пример использования:

Сначала устанавливаем пакет pywin32: `pip install pywin32`

```
import win32console
import time

for i in range(10):
    win32console.FreeConsole()
    time.sleep(5)
    win32console.AllocConsole()
    print('Hello!', i)
    time.sleep(5)
```